# Full-width H1 vs "normal" size

Tags: website-design, design, web

Is there any best practice as to what to prefer from a UX perspective between a full width header title such as [this](https://www.frantoiocavalli.com/) and a more normal header size?

I have a consumer facing brand and it's important to have good enough UX for the users to easily access and interact with the site. Everything else will be the same (CTA on the same place, etc.), but the size of the header will differ.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is not a good practice to have large, lengthy h1 tags.

Looking around your site, however, I think what the designer has done is appropriate. The h1 headers are one or two words, not lengthy lines that can cause users to [struggle with readability](https://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability). The rest of the pages don't seem to have a large amount of content that the user urgently needs to get to.

The titles are elements of the visual design, as one would see in a traditional magazine ad. The markup structure appears correct and I don't see any UX issues with the headings.

I do think your menu items are problematically large, and would bump those down a bit - I had to scroll to get through a not-very-long list of items, and that felt unnecessary.